# Палательные и мягкие звуки

Tags: языкознание

Почему звуки русского языка называют в одних случаях палательными, а в других - мягкими?

Answer (score 2):

От контекста зависит, вернее от обсуждаемой темы.
Школьникам, например, понятие палат**а**лизации давать излишне.

И вообще, при обсуждении фонетической оппозиции по твердости-мягкости в **русском** языке вполне уместно звуки называть мягкими. А вот когда обсуждается проблемы, выходящие за рамки русского языка (общая фонетическая теория, например), то понятие "мягкости" неприменимо. Звуки стоит называть палатализованными.

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос вопрошающему: кто употребляет отсутствующее в русском языке слово "палательные", и где вы его могли слышать? Ведь в лекции по фонетике, скорее всего, был употреблен термин "палатализованные" (или, на худой конец, "палатАльные" - от латинского слова "palatum").

Comment: Да это скорее всего банальная опечатка. Не стоит так уж акцентировать.

Comment: Иван Стрельцов выдвинул гениальную гипотезу о звуках русской речи, но малопонятные ошибки у него *проскакивают*) Например, Ивана Александровича Бодуэна де Куртенэ он упорно называет *Болдуэном*(?) Шутит, наверное...

Comment: Не знаю, кто такой Стрельцов, а Болдуин (Baldwin) - вполне себе английская фамилия.